# Efficiency of structural recursion vs tail recursion

Tags: haskell

I want to know the difference between executing

```
factorial 0 = 0
factorial n = n * factorial (n-1)
```

and

```
factorial 0 r = r
factorial n r = factorial (n-1) (r * n)
```

Wich is more performant?

Comment: It is best you'll do some measurements/benchmarks with criterion and run some heap profiles as well. There is a chapter in resl world haskell about heap profiles and criterion has good documentation. And it is an easy enough task for a beginner to not be overwhelmed with

Comment: One thing I would encourage you to play around is adding variants with strictness annotations (with `BangPatterns`) and different levels of optimization `-O0` .. `-O2` and variants with type signatures.

Comment: Did you do any benchmarks before asking this question?

Comment: I want to know the performance not only of ```factorial```. In general, wich is better, structural recursion or tail recursion. I can't benchmark that. Only ```factorial``` is not a proof.

Comment: There is no real answer to this question. Sometimes one is faster, sometimes the other one. Try transforming `f n = n : f (n+1)` to a tail recursive function, for instance, and see how fast it diverges :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure either is. The first will evaluate `n-1` in the pattern test for 0, but will produce a stack of multiplications that can't begin to execute until it reaches `0`. The second will produce that same stack stored in the `r` argument. The advantage of the second, however, is that you can make the `r` argument strict and be purely tail recursive in constant space, because its multiplication order agrees with the call order.

We can interpret the first version as `factorial n = foldr (*) 1 [n,n-1..1]`, and the second as `factorial n = foldl (*) 1 [n,n-1..1]`. Thus the difference in strictness for `r` is the same as between [`foldl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl) and [`foldl'`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldl-39-). But if the list is long and the operation can shortcut by not inspecting the second argument, the [`foldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldr) version gets a noted advantage.

Comment: The second version will be optimized properly by GHC's demand analysis for typical numerical types if you use `-O` or `-O2`.